# How to convert hex number to color?

Tags: c#, button, colors, server, client

I have a system where I'm the server and there's a client that will be sending data to me. Once I receive the data, for example: FB 00 00 00 00 00 00 FF 00 0D, I have to convert this data into button's color. I do not want the code. I want to know how so that I know where to start with.

Comment: What colour do you expect `FB 00 00 00 00 00 00 FF 00 0D` to represent..?

Comment: for example, FB..... will display red and FA ... will display green.

Comment: Do you have a particular rule for finding the colour? Colours are typically represented with 6 hex digits. For example, red would be FF0000

Comment: for example: {FB 00 00 00 10 01 00 FF 00 0D} 
the 01 represents red color
10 represents green color

Comment: I honestly don't see the logic in these examples....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using System.Drawing;

...
...
...
...
ColorConverter converter = new ColorConverter();
Color myColor = (Color)converter.ConvertFromInvariantString("#FF0000");
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert your hex number to integer

```
int intColor = int.Parse("FF0000",system.Globalization.NumberStyle.HexNumber);
```

then get color from integr

```
Color c=Color.FromArgb(intColor);
```